# How to create "custom page types" with different custom fields in them?

Tags: customization, pages, admin, advanced-custom-fields, post-editor

I have lots of pages that perform very different purposes in my website (landing pages, thank you pages, regular website pages, webinar pages, etc).

As such, I would like to group my pages into different "types".

Stage one is (I'm guessing) to figure out how to apply some kind of "page type" flag to pages. I suppose I could use custom fields for this, but I don't know if there is something more built in to WordPress that I should be using rather than creating a custom field, or if generally there are other things I should consider before getting started down this path.

Supplementary information (in case this affects the answer):

In addition to the core requirement, here are two other main considerations that may (or may not!) impact the approach needed (these do not need to be spoken to, I just add them for consideration):

1. I would like each page type to be able to have different custom fields in the editing page, depending on the page type (eg, 'webinar' type page may want to have a 'webinar date' field, landing page might want to have 'thank you page URL' field, etc).
2. Ultimately I would like to be able to add tabs to the Pages page that displays the page types similar to how Elementor treats their templates, ie:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use either a custom taxonomy or a custom field for page types. By the nature of custom taxonomy, I think it's a better solution than custom field.

To create custom fields for each page type, you can use a plugin like [Meta Box](https://metabox.io) along with [Conditional Logic](https://metabox.io/plugins/meta-box-conditional-logic/) or [Include Exclude](https://metabox.io/plugins/meta-box-include-exclude/) extension. They allow you to define custom fields for posts/pages under some conditions such as by taxonomy terms, categories, page templates, or by other custom fields' values.

Regarding creating tabs for page types, I guess it's a custom code. WordPress doesn't support it by default. Maybe you can look at Elementor's code to see how they do that.

Comment: Thanks @Anh! A bit of code for registering a custom taxonomy, as well as any reference(s) would make this answer more helpful, too.

Comment: Also I reached out to Meta Box describing my use case and I will see what they recommend.